# Pre 1900 date can't be formatted

Tags: excel-2016

I have a problem when format date with date pre 1900, as those date will not be formatted with date formatting. How to get over this problem?

[image]

Comment: You show examples in your question of pre-1990 dates formatted correctly.

Comment: @ThomasJager Good catch thnks

Comment: According to this page http://www.exceluser.com/formulas/earlydates.htm, (which seems to be correct) dates before 1900 are not included because of an error made in Lotus 1-2-3 which left in Feb. 29th in a non-leap-year. To avoid incompatibilities, all dates before this were removed. Although I can't verify the justification, so don't believe what I've written, it would make sense as the non-existing date is still present.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_1900_problem

Answer (score 0):

If a date is before 01/01/1900 cannot be treated as date in Excel, you can eventually express it as a string, by using a heading apos i.e. '01/01/1888

CIT: "When you enter a date, the date is converted into a serial number that represents the number of elapsed days since January 1, 1900. For example, if you enter July 5, 1998, Excel converts the date to the serial number 35981."

More details at:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/214330/differences-between-the-1900-and-the-1904-date-system-in-excel